# webClient.DownloadData throw 'System.IO.PathTooLongException'

Tags: c#, system.io.file

I have an method which is download images via URL and sometimes URL become like this, which contains very long path (i removed some string,it just didnt beacome long question :) : 
 
 `data:image/jpeg;base64,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`

And then when i debug or when its come to download image, i get this Exception:

> var DL = webClient.DownloadData(base64)
>   The specified path and / or file name is too long. The fully qualified
>   name must be less than 260 characters and the folder name must be less
>   than 248 characters.

i did also research which is suggested to add `<httpRuntime maxUrlLength="260" />` in webconfig or used different library , but unfortunately it didnt help to solve the problem.

Can anyone please help me or point me into the right direction :)

Thanks in advance.
Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public string DownloadImagesFromLinkViaURL(ImagesViewModel model)
{
 var RandomName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N").Substring(0,12);
    using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
    {
        try
        {
            string base64 = model.ImageURL.Substring(model.ImageURL.IndexOf(',') + 1);
            byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
            var DL = webClient.DownloadData(base64);

            using (MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream(DL))
            {
                using (var content = Image.FromStream(mem))
                {
                    var format = ImageFormat.Png.ToString().ToLower();

                    var PathIMG = "https://SomeName.com/folder/" + RandomName + "." + format;

                    content.Save(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(PathIMG)));
                    ImageStore img = new ImageStore();

                    img.ProducentVarenr = model.ImageName;
                    img.ImageOrginalURL = model.ImageURL;
                    img.ImageRandomName = RandomName;
                    img.LinktilBillede = PathIMG;
                    db.ImageStoreList.Add(img);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
            }

        }
        catch (ArgumentException)
        {
            return "content is not image";
        }

    }
    return "saved";
}
```

ViewModal:

```
public class ImagesViewModel
{
    public int ImageID { get; set; }
    public string ImageURL { get; set; }
    public string ImageName { get; set; }
    public string ImagePath { get; set; }
    public string RandomName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Is it not path, it's base64-encoded data of the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data you see is not url or path. It is image data presented as [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) string. So no any downloading is needed since you have image data already.

If you paste that *very long string* i.e [this](http://%20https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter) base64-to-image converter tool, you see actual image.

With given base64-string you can save it to file with following style:

```
File.WriteAllBytes(@"c:\yourfile", Convert.FromBase64String(base64));
```

Here is (non-tested and non-refactored) fixed version of your original method, as requested in answer comments.

```
[HttpPost]
public string DownloadImagesFromLinkViaURL(ImagesViewModel model)
{
    var RandomName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N").Substring(0, 12);
    var format = ImageFormat.Png.ToString().ToLower();

    var PathIMG = "https://SomeName.com/folder/" + RandomName + "." + format;
    if (model.ImageURL.StartsWith("data:image"))
    {
        string base64 = model.ImageURL.Substring(model.ImageURL.IndexOf(',') + 1);
        File.WriteAllBytes($@"c:\temp\{RandomName}.jpeg", Convert.FromBase64String(base64));
        ImageStore img = new ImageStore();

        img.ProducentVarenr = model.ImageName;
        img.ImageOrginalURL = model.ImageURL;
        img.ImageRandomName = RandomName;
        img.LinktilBillede = PathIMG;
        db.ImageStoreList.Add(img);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return "saved";
    }
    using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
            var DL = webClient.DownloadData(base64);

            using (MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream(DL))
            {
                using (var content = Image.FromStream(mem))
                {
                    content.Save(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(PathIMG)));
                    ImageStore img = new ImageStore();

                    img.ProducentVarenr = model.ImageName;
                    img.ImageOrginalURL = model.ImageURL;
                    img.ImageRandomName = RandomName;
                    img.LinktilBillede = PathIMG;
                    db.ImageStoreList.Add(img);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
            }

        }
        catch (ArgumentException)
        {
            return "content is not image";
        }

    }
    return "saved";
}
```

Comment: as you see in my code i tried also to convert base64 to image and than download image and save it to some folder but its throw exception.

Comment: Downloading is wrong. `webClient.DownloadData(base64)` will throw exception since `base64` does not contain any url/path.

Comment: What do you want to do with that image data? save to file?

Comment: i just want to download images via url and than save it to an folder. and i only have problem with the images which contains data:image/jpeg;base64,/someRandomString otherwise the method working fine

Comment: I updated answer, so saving is very simple operation

Comment: Would you please tell me , where should i put the code , beacuse i tried to put in  using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
    {} i get some errors.

Comment: I updated answer but notice that I did not have any possibility to test my code so bugs might occur..

Comment: Thanks for help Risto :)

Comment: Happy to help! :)